# I'm trying to make ImageProcessor in swift but getting an error

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

let image = UIImage(named: "sample.png")

// Process the image!

var myRGBA = RGBAImage(image: image!)

let avgRed = 122
let avgGreen = 113
let avgBlue = 51

for y in 0..<myRGBA?.height {
    for x in 0..<myRGBA?.width {
        let index = y * (myRGBA?.width)! + x
        var pixel = myRGBA?.pixels[index]
        let redDiff = Int(pixel.red) - avgRed
        if (redDiff>0)
        {
            pixel.red = UInt8( max(0, min(255,avgRed + redDiff * 5)))
            myRGBA?.pixels[index] = pixel
        }
    }
}

let newImage2 = myRGBA?.toUIImage()
```

The error is saying -> Binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Int?'

The RGBAImage is running smooth without any errors

I'm writing the code in swift 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed few things now the code below works for me

```
import UIKit

let image = UIImage(named: "sample.png")

// Process the image!

var myRGBA = RGBAImage(image: image!)

let avgRed = 122
let avgGreen = 113
let avgBlue = 51

if let unwrapped = myRGBA {
    for y in 0..<unwrapped.height {
        for x in 0..<unwrapped.width {
            let index = y * (myRGBA?.width)! + x
            var pixel = myRGBA?.pixels[index]
            let redDiff = Int((pixel?.red)!) - avgRed
            if (redDiff>0)
            {
                pixel?.red = UInt8( max(0, min(255,avgRed + redDiff * 5)))
                myRGBA?.pixels[index] = pixel!
            }
        }
    }
}

let newImage2 = myRGBA?.toUIImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to unwrap your optional

```
import UIKit

let image = UIImage(named: "sample.png")

// Process the image!

var myRGBA = RGBAImage(image: image!)

let avgRed = 122
let avgGreen = 113
let avgBlue = 51
if let unwrapped = myRGBA?{
for y in 0..< unwrapped.height {
    for x in 0..< unwrapped.width {
        let index = y * (myRGBA?.width)! + x
        var pixel = myRGBA?.pixels[index]
        let redDiff = Int(pixel.red) - avgRed
        if (redDiff>0)
        {
            pixel.red = UInt8( max(0, min(255,avgRed + redDiff * 5)))
            myRGBA?.pixels[index] = pixel
        }
    }
}
}
let newImage2 = myRGBA?.toUIImage()
```

Comment: With the above code I have these errors ->  1 Expected '{' to start the body of for-each loop,  2 Braced block of statements is an unused closure,  3 Use of unresolved identifier 'y',  4 Use of unresolved identifier 'x'

Comment: and this one ->  '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for the error:**

Optional comparison is not supported by default in Swift 3.0.

So you need to **overload** the comparison operators on your own or swift migrator will do it for you if you are migrating your code to Swift 3.0.

Overloaded methods look like this:

```
fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}

fileprivate func > <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l > r
  default:
    return rhs < lhs
  }
}
```